# How to execute code, and re-execute code if server stops responding?

Tags: python, error-handling, try-catch

I am trying to scrape data from the website http://lmi2.detma.org/lmi/lmi_es_a.asp and occasionally the website stops responding. This causes my code to continue running without doing anything. I want to abort the current code, and restart

Right now I just hit stop and execute again, but I want to do this automatically

My current Code is:

```
try:
    exec(open('filename.py').read()) #code that might fail

except:
    #error handling if code failed
```

The problem is that when the website stops responding, there is no error message, the script just keeps on running without doing anything so the code loop of try never fails

Answer (score 0):

`exec` will create a new subproccess, execute `filename.py` in that proccess, and then wait for that new subproccess to finish.

There's nothing you can do in your current code.. it would be best to modify `filename.py` so that if it doesn't receive any response in, say, 1 minute, it will just restart (in a while loop or something of the sort).

Comment: Thank you very much Christopher. Looks like ill just keep doing it the long way since that seems like less work